# Vaadin 24 - Change Cursor to Wait While Loading Indicator is Shown?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I've looked at the docs for Loading Indicator (https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/loading-indicator) - but it really only describes how to change the indicator itself, not how to use CSS to change the curstor to a "wait" cursor.

**Situation:** I have a grid and depending on the filtering options selected, it can take up to 1=2 seconds to filter the list. During this time the default progress indicator (the blue bar at the top of the screen) is showing the progress. I'd like to change the cursor to the "wait" cursor when that progress indicator is visible.

I had a look at this old forum post (for Vaadin 6,7,8) that gave some CSS - https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18376129/wait-cursor-in-grid but the selectors have obviously changed in Vaadin 24 because using that CSS in the example didn't do anything:

```
.v-loading-indicator[style*="display: block"] ~ * {
    cursor: wait !important;
}

.v-loading-indicator.first[style*="display: block"]  ~ * {
    cursor: wait !important;
}

.v-loading-indicator.second[style*="display: block"]  ~ * {
    cursor: wait !important;
}

.v-loading-indicator.third[style*="display: block"] ~ * {
    cursor: wait !important;
}
```

I would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the quoted CSS has not worked ever. The cursor style should be set on element that occupies the the space underneath the mouse pointer. Hence you should try to target the `body` tag, something like this.

```
body:has(.v-loading-indicator[style*="display: block"]) {
  cursor: wait !important;
}
```

Note, that even this is not 100%. Some elements may have overriden the mouse pointer style like buttons or so. So whether the mouse pointer changes depends a bit on which element the pointer is hovering, but the above example works in most cases.

Comment: Tatu - thanks very much! I figured that it was something simple - and I REALLY appreciate your quick response. Thank you!

IS there a way to change the cursor if it's hovering over a button and the loading indicator is showing?